# How this command works?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Sorry I`m a newbie in python. While studying pyspark, I came across a command like this

```
sc = SparkSession.builder.config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "file:///C:/temp").appName("SparkSQL").getOrCreate()
```

My doubt is very basic, I just want to know how the dot operator is used multiple times in the above statement. As per my knowledge dot operator will be used multiple times when a function is within multiple levels of packages like

```
packagemain.subpackage1.subpackage2.function()
```

But in the above statement the "SparkSession" seems to be a Class and "sc" is an object, others may be functions. I just want to know how they are linked together by a dot operator? How the system interprets this above statement?

Comment: Well, no, the "dot notation" isn't for packages only. It's for objects and their _attributes_ in general. The [official Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/classes.html) has an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

A spark config file is a series of keys: values, separated by whitespace, eg.: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html

```
.config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "file:///C:/temp")
```

refers to a configuration object, built from the file being referenced, and looking for a key called `spark.sql.warehouse.dir`

This is simply a string (or more specifically, the name of a key in the config file) - nothing to do with imports or any of the like.

Answer (score 0):

It gets the builder from SparkSession. From that builder it calls config with the arguments. That returns some config which you then call the appName function on with the next arguments. Then from that it calls the getOrCreate() function.
Basically it returns the value of the calls before the dot, then evaluate the dot code on that.

Comment: Yes after reading the source doc, I clearly understood, thanks Albert